# Close Vuetify dialog with Vuex

Tags: vue.js, vuex, vuetify.js, vuex-modules

After hours of searching and trying to find the correct method my n00b brain exploded.
I've tried so many things that I'm complete lost. Everything works like I want it to, can remove the customer I want, the front refreshes etc. Except the dialog.

Can you please explain how to close this dialog?

Here is my dialog.

```
<template>
  <div>
    <template>
      <tbody>
        <tr v-for="customer in AllCustomers" :key="customer.id" class="todo">
          <td>{{customer.ID}}</td>
          <td>{{ customer.name }}</td>
          <td>{{customer.telephone}}</td>
          <td>{{customer.email}}</td>
          <v-btn color="success" @click="showDeleteDialog(customer)">DELETE</v-btn>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </template>
    <v-dialog v-model="dialogDelete" persistent max-width="500px">
      <v-card>
        <v-card-title>Delete</v-card-title>
        <v-card-text>Weet je zeker dat je {{customerToDelete}} wenst te verwijderen?</v-card-text>
        <v-card-actions>
          <v-btn color="primary" text @click="close">Annuleer</v-btn>
          <v-btn color="primary" text @click="deleteCustomer(customer.ID)">Verwijderen</v-btn>
        </v-card-actions>
      </v-card>
    </v-dialog>
  </div>
</template>



<script>
import { mapGetters, mapActions, mapState } from "vuex";

export default {
  name: "AllCustomers",

  data() {
    return {
      customerToDelete: "",
      dialogDelete: false
    };
  },

  methods: {
    ...mapActions(["fetchAllCustomers", "deleteCustomer"]),

    async close() {
      this.dialogDelete = false;
    },

    async showDeleteDialog(customer) {
      this.customer = Object.assign({}, customer);
      this.customerToDelete = this.customer.name;
      this.dialogDelete = !this.dialogDelete;
      this.$store.commit("toggleDialog");
    }
  },

  computed: mapGetters(["AllCustomers"]),
  created() {
    this.fetchAllCustomers();
  },
  ...mapState(["dialogDelete"])
};
</script>
```

And here my module js.

```
import axios from 'axios';

const state = {
    customers: [],
    dialogDelete: false
};

const getters = {
    AllCustomers: state => state.customers
};

const actions = {
    async fetchAllCustomers({ commit }) {
        const response = await axios.get(
            'http://localhost:8888'
        );
        console.log(response.data.data);
        commit('setAllCustomers', response.data.data);
    },

    async deleteCustomer({ commit }, id) {
        await axios.delete(`http://localhost:8888/delete`, {
            data: {
                id: id
            }
        })
        console.log(id)
        commit('removeCustomer', id, this.dialogDelete = false);
    },

}

const mutations = {
    setAllCustomers: (state, customers) => (state.customers = customers),
    removeCustomer: (state, id) =>
        (state.customers = state.customers.filter(customer => customer.ID !== id)),
}

export default {
    state,
    getters,
    actions,
    mutations
};
```

Comment: It doesn't looks like close() is defined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use mapState to get your dialogDelete variable from store:

```
 // in your dialog
 import { mapState } from "vuex"

 computed: {
 ...mapState(["dialogDelete"])
 }
```

and you should change its state in mutations with a commit:

```
// in vuex store
const mutations = {
setAllCustomers: (state, customers) => (state.customers = customers),
removeCustomer: (state, id) =>
    (state.customers = state.customers.filter(customer => customer.ID !== 
id)),
toggleDialog: (state) => (state.dialogDelete = !state.dialogDelete)    
}

// in your dialog
this.$store.commit("toggleDialog")
```

Comment: thank you but where does this.$store.commit("toggleDialog") go?

Comment: this is how you trigger the methods in vuex mutations. $store refers to Vuex.Store which controls state, actions, getters and mutations.

Comment: yes I know. But what i meant was were do I place this part inside the code? You say in the dialog but where

Comment: if you just want to close the dialog window by clicking close just set @click="dialogDelete = false"> or you can call this.$store.commit("toggleDialog") from a method that you want to open or close it.

Comment: I don't want just the dialog to close, it also needs to actually needs to delete the item from the database. This works, except the dialog not closing is the issue. So I'm struggling to combine these two actions.

Comment: then add this.$store.commit("toggleDialog") to the method that you delete the items.

Answer (score 0):

Since you didn't include the `<script>` tag in your code, I'm assuming that you're trying to toggle the vuex state directly by your close event from the vue component, which wouldn't work this way.
Instead, you would want to dispatch an action that commits a mutation that toggles the vuex state.

However, a better idea is to encapsulate the dialog component in a separate vue SFC (single file component) that has a local state`isActive`, which you can toggle on or off via a local method `this.isActive = false`, and once you import that component you then give it a ref `ref="deleteDialog"`, you'll then be able to access the component's internal methods like this: `this.$refs.deleteDialog.close()`

For more info about refs, see the [docs](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-edge-cases.html#Accessing-Child-Component-Instances-amp-Child-Elements).

**EDIT**

So for example:

`DialogDelete.vue`

```
<template>
    <v-dialog v-model="isActive" persistent max-width="500px">
      <v-card>
        <v-card-title>Delete</v-card-title>
        <v-card-text>Weet je zeker dat je {{customerToDelete}} wenst te verwijderen?</v-card-text>
        <v-card-actions>
          <v-btn color="primary" text @click="close">Annuleer</v-btn>
          <v-btn color="primary" text @click="deleteCustomer(customer.ID)">Verwijderen</v-btn>
        </v-card-actions>
      </v-card>
    </v-dialog>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    data() {
      return {
        isActive: false
      }
    },
    methods: {
      close() {
        this.isActive = false
      },
      open() {
        this.isActive = true
      }
    },
  }
</script>
```

`Parent.vue`

```
<template>
  <div>
    <v-btn @click="openDialog">Open Dialog</v-btn>
    <dialog-delete ref="deleteDialog" />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    components: {
      dialogDelete: () => import("./DialogDelete.vue"),
    },

    methods: {
      openDialog() {
        this.$refs.deleteDialog.open()
      }
    },
  }
</script>
```

It's also clear to me that you're not placing the vuex helper methods (like `mapGetters` & `mapState`) where they should be, for example both of `mapState` & `mapGetters` should be within the `computed`:

```
computed: {
  ...mapGetters(["getterName"]),
  ...mapState(["stateName"])
}
```

check out the [vuex docs](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/state.html#the-mapstate-helper).

Comment: I did the update with the script now. Would you mind showing me your solution?

Comment: I've done like you said, but when I press the "open dialog" I get the error that this.$refs.deleteDialog.open() isn't a function....

Comment: Here, take a look at this:

https://codesandbox.io/s/blue-resonance-ndhtc

Comment: thank you for this but it just doesn't work. I have everything the same but still get the same error